# USB3320 REFCLK Pin

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

I'm looking at the Zybo USB OTG Schematic and the USB3320 datasheet. I noticed that USB3320's REFCLK pin is not connected. I read in the datasheet that the refclk pin needs to be connected to the crystal. Can you explain why the REFCLK pin and the crystal are not connected?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to that schematic, the REFCLK pin is connected. It's driven by a net called `USB_CLK_12M`.

To find out what is driving that net you will have to look elsewhere in the schematic for another net that has the same label.

---

Unless you are referring to the `XO` pin?

There are two options for clocking the USB3320, either feeding it directly with a CMOS clock, or using a resonator.

To use a resonator, you connect one end to `REFCLK` and the other to `XO`:

[image: Resonator or Crystal Connection for USB3320]
<sup>Image from USB3320 Datasheet</sup>

To use a CMOS clock, you connect the clock directly to `REFCLK` and float (leave unconnected) `XO` as is done in this schematic:

[image]
[image]
<sup>Image from USB3320 Datasheet</sup>